# Vue - can't show image src

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to setup a page where my vue frontend receives a qr code url from my backend. The problem is that for some reason the image is not showing. I created a simple example where `request_code` simulates my backend. Here is [the codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-mendel-k9i2s?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-717).

Whenever i try to load the image in my Vue app, i get a 400 error, but if i copy the image url and open it on my browser, it will show. How can i fix this?

Code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ qr_code }}</h1>
    <img :src="qr_code" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      qr_code: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.request_code();
  },
  methods: {
    request_code() {
      this.qr_code =
        "https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/xyTrade:root?secret=7UORYWFJCLXY4OLEWMZWQMJ2QYGK5OFI&issuer=xyTrade";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine for me: https://k9i2s.csb.app

Comment: Do you see the QR code? I'm using Chrome and the image doesn't load. Same on Edge

Comment: In Firefox I initially get "400 Bad Request" in codesandbox, but when pasting the URL into a new tab, it shows up fine, and afterwards it shows in codesandbox as well (probably due to caching).

Comment: Yeah indeed the problem is that when i try to show it in my Vue application i get a 400, but if i try to open the image in my browser it will show

Comment: It seems like a known problem: if you change the path from `google.com` to `charts.googleapis.com`, then the correct mime type will be returned for the first request and the issue will go away.

Comment: Changing it to charts.googleapis worked! Thanks a lot @Terry!! Can you post this as an answer so that i can accept it?

Comment: @JayK23 The answer already exists :) that's why I closed this question as a duplicate. See the linked question at the top of the page.

Answer (score -1):

What i find is that you haven't applied async/await against the request_code by applying async/await it works great.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ qr_code }}</h1>
    <img :src="qr_code" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      qr_code: "",
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.request_code();
  },
  methods: {
    request_code() {
      this.qr_code =
        "https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/xyTrade:root?secret=7UORYWFJCLXY4OLEWMZWQMJ2QYGK5OFI&issuer=xyTrade";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but the image doesn't show and i get this in my console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Comment: There is no point in using async/await here since you are setting the image source, which is a string, directly. It is not an asynchronous operation to begin with.

Comment: Do you have vue extension installed? If yes please check this.qr_code got the value? As code works fine on the sandbox that you have shared

Comment: @Terry it doesn't seem to be a image link as images usually have a extension with them. It seems to be a api call to get an qr code image

Comment: @Faisal Extensions != response mime type. You can have any arbitrary URL that returns an image mime type. The API call **generates an image** (i.e. returns an image mime type).